# How to override data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem and i really wish you could help me with this.. $this is my code in my UI and I kind of wanna pass this data to the my modal.

The thing is this code worked, it passed the data to the modal, but the data can't be over ride and I don't know why.

I already am doing the loop but i guess the data is not being override..

```
<?php $this->load->view('popups/categoryPopups'); 
    foreach ($categories as $category) : ?>
    <tr>
        <th><?php echo $category['cat_name']; ?></th>
        <th><ul>
            <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('/categories/items/' .$category['cat_id']); ?>">Items</a></li>
            <li><button id="rename"
                data-id="<?php echo $category['cat_id']; ?>" 
                data-name="<?php echo $category['cat_name']; ?>" 
                data-toggle="modal" data-target="#rename_cat_modal">Rename
            </button></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('/categories/hide/'. $category['cat_id']); ?>" class="btn btn-warning">Remove</a></li>
            </ul>
        </th>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This is my javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $("#rename").click(function(){
            var cat_id = $("#rename").data('id');
            var cat_name = $("#rename").data('name');
            $("#catName").val( cat_name );
        }); 
    }); 
</script>
```

and this is my modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="rename_cat_modal">
    <?php echo form_open('categories/rename_cat'); ?>
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title"><b>Rename Category</b></h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                     <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label style="padding-left: 5px;"><b>Enter New Name</b></label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cat_name" id="catName" value="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: i do not see any element with the id catName. what are you trying to rename. also considering there may be many categories then using ids (button id rename) instead of classes is the wrong approach. lastly you are calling $('#rename') very many times yet it is an expensive operation to search the dom.

Comment: I still haven't take care about the  renaming thing.. I need to pass the data first, so please don't focus on the rename..

Comment: and in the $('#rename') i'm trying to get the value of the id and the name.. :D

Comment: you mean $(this). i already mentioned that since its in a loop there may be many categories and many buttons with id #rename

Comment: the id catName is in the modal code in the modal body.. the input element..

Comment: so i can change the $("#rename") into $(this)??

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think i have done changes in your code try this.

```
<?php $this->load->view('popups/categoryPopups'); 
foreach ($categories as $category) : ?>
<tr>
    <th><?php echo $category['cat_name']; ?></th>
    <th><ul>
        <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('/categories/items/' 
         .$category['cat_id']); ?>">Items</a></li>
        <li><button class="rename"
            data-id="<?php echo $category['cat_id']; ?>" 
            data-name="<?php echo $category['cat_name']; ?>" 
            data-toggle="modal" data-target="#rename_cat_modal">Rename
        </button></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('/categories/hide/'. 
            $category['cat_id']); ?>" class="btn btn-
           warning">Remove</a></li>
        </ul>
     </th>
      </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>


 changes in your jquery 

<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(".rename").click(function(){
        var cat_id = $("this).data('id');
        var cat_name = $(this).data('name');
        $("#catName").val( cat_name );
    }); 
}); 
</script>
```

it should work .use class instead of id as there are many rows and id is used for specific element

Comment: It worked, thanks.. i've learned so much just from this simple problem.. you saved me literally .. LOL